# Maven use dependency from dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have 3 proyects on maven, A, B and C

B has a dependency to C.

And A has a dependency to C.

This is my pom From C

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>C</name>
    <description>C proyect</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

C also has a public class

```
package com.test.C;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Example{

    private String exampl1;

    private String codexampl1igo;


}
```

This is the POM of B proyect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>B</name>
    <description>B proyect</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And this is the POM of A proyect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>A</name>
    <description>A proyect</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

So as you can see I have in A proyect a dependency with B proyect and the B proyect has a dependency to C proyect.

There is a way to use the public class Example in C proyect in A proyect?

Comment: Class `Example` should be available. Do you find that it is not?

Comment: I cant find it, is not in the classpath and the IDE doesnt recognice it.

Comment: And you ran `mvn install` on each project, A, B and C ?

Comment: Yes, on each proyect I ran `mvn clean install`